# adding full text search to a SQL Express table

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I am developing in C# MVC Visual studio using sql express. Running my application on localhost, then i push final app to production which runs sql server.
I would like to know how do I add full-text indexing to my existing table:

```
CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX ON dbo.People
(  
    Title,  
    Authors,
    Description  
)
```

So  this query above where do i run it on visual studio as I am using sql express?

How about migrations? Do I need to add anything to my model.cs class? And do I need to enable migrations add fulltext search?

I could do this easily in php/mysql, but i am learning c# mvc so I am not sure what is required.

Comment: How does C# MVC relate to your fulltext searching problem?  What technology are you using to connect to your database?

Comment: I don't think SQL Express even supports full-text search. What version are you using?

Comment: really there is no support for sql express, hmm. @Matthew what technology as in connecting with connection strings in my web.config? and changing the connection strings whenever i am pushing to production. is that what you mean? sorry i am not sure what you mean technology as i mentioned everythingi am using in the question. thanks

Comment: What is the actual question you are asking? Is it that you don't know how to connect your application to the db? The connection string syntax can be easily find by googleing.

Comment: the question i am asking if you know how c# mvc works, you need to declare all your db structure in the model, then you do migrations, so now that i want to alter table and add full-text search, what is the process required as i am not sure how to include that in my model and migrations. thanks

Comment: You can make this change from the server after the table is created in management studio.

Comment: @Dunbar thanks for your response. so all i need is run the query in production, and all is good? great thanks.

Comment: I cant tell if your being sarcastic or not lol. I was merely stating that the changes your asking can be make from management studio. Obviously, you should test this in dev first.

Comment: @Dunbar no sarcasm here. i really mean thanks! i find any single tweak i make to the db in mvc c#, i have to do enable migrations, etc, and this can be frustrating so your response was all i needed. thanks again.

Comment: Get sql server express with advanced tools for full text searching http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=1842

Comment: @PaulZahra, great link.  It specifically says in the fine print that it includes full-text.  Interesting another page on SQL Server Express features says that full-text is not included. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165636%28v=sql.105%29.aspx .  You should post this as an answer, it does answer the question.

Comment: @Samuel Neff Hmm that is a bit confusing, I guess they are only talking about the non advanced tools version of SQL Express.

Answer (score 2):

Get sql server express with advanced tools for full text searching [here a link](http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=1842)

If you expand the details section it states:

"
Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Express with Advanced Services is a free, easy-to-use version of the SQL Server Express data platform that includes an advanced graphical management tool and powerful features for reporting and **advanced text-based searches**. This edition provides powerful and reliable data management tools and rich features, data protection, and fast performance. It is ideal for small server applications and local data stores.
"

EDIT: For some coding pointers [have a read of this SO post and it's replies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1512996/search-database-asp-net-mvc-c-sharp) and also look at the links on the lower right of this page for 'similar' topics that may well be of interest. Over there -------->